# Stage file by its file name, regardless of directory--Git

Tags: git

I have *very* nested directories in a project, and I'm a lazy programmer.

Let's say I have a file name `EventEditor.foo` I want to stage my file regardless of whether it's in the root directory or `./src/holy/sweet/mother/of/baby/raptor/jesus/this/is/a/long/hiearchy/EventEditor.foo`

My goal would be to be all, "Yo Git, add EventEditor" and bam. It stages it with me only having to type something like `git add *EventEdi*`. Is this possible? Or am I day dreaming?

Comment: Just want to check to see if my answer meets your needs; you haven't accepted it, so I want to make sure it's working out for you, or have you let me know what's not working or you're confused about so I can explain.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope that explains how it works to your satisfaction now. Let me know if you have any more trouble.

Comment: Darn those sweet mother of baby raptor jesus files... they give me headaches all the time...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you would like to match a glob recursively when using [`git add`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html), start the glob you pass in to `git add` with a directory name (such as `.` for the current directory), and make sure that the glob is in quotes so that Git can interpret it instead of the shell:

`git add "./*EventEdi*"`

A full example:

```
$ git init git-add
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/lambda/tmp/stackoverflow/git-add/.git/
$ cd git-add/
$ mkdir -p foo/bar/baz
$ touch foo/bar/baz/some-long-filename.txt
$ git add "./*long-filename*"
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo/bar/baz/some-long-filename.txt
#
```

From the [manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html):

> Fileglobs (e.g. `*.c`) can be given to add all matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to add `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to add all files in the directory, recursively.

Comment: No, this didn't work at all. Git (1.7.1) accepts the add, does not give me any messages saying it did not find any files with that 'pathspec', and prints nothing to stdo. 

Normally I get something like `fatal: pathspec '<my pattern>' did not match any files`

Comment: @Jonathan If you get nothing printed to stdout, that probably means that it worked. `git add`, like many Unix commands, prints nothing upon success. Check `git status` to see if the file has been added.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Screenshot of the commands I used: http://imgur.com/1aIvO.png

Comment: @Jonathan Dumaine: Brian’s answer shows that Git does “pathspec” processing (a kind of wildcard matching) for *new* files, but your posted screen shot involves *updated* files. Unfortunately, `git add` does not (currently) do pathspec-style matching for updated files. This inconsistency in `git add` was fixed (along with several other pathspec issues) in 898bbd9 of the *nd/pathspec* topic which has been [merged to *master* ](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=d5c87a802d3b0bcd37b38d117648f342e7ad62d2) (i.e. it will be in Git 1.7.5).

Comment: @Chris Johnsen Ah, I was wondering about that. I was able to reproduce Jonathan's problem, and started looking into it, but wound up not having time to track it all the way down and fix it. Thanks for the heads up on the fix!

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/micrddrgn/bce61039913d74421d8a) is a bash alias to be able to add multiple files at once like `gitadd foo.js bar.rb dme.md`

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Linux, you can easily use something like :

```
find . -name EventEditor.foo -exec git add {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Brian's answer is pretty *shifty* ;)
But you may also find useful:

```
git add -i
```

or

```
gitg
```

Comment: Yes interactive mode is 'okay' but it requires you to find the file you're looking for and then associate with a random number (not to mention having to do separate sub-modes for `[u]pdate` and `[a]dd untracked`. If I already know the file name I'm looking for, and it is unique, it would be much easier to type a partial blob of the file name.

Comment: Also, I do from time to time use gitx.

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of git you can just do the expected

```
git add '*EventEditor.foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small tool ([git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number)) that allows me to use numbers instead of filenames when dealing with files in git.

"git number" runs git status and inserts number for each filename that is shown, sequentially.

After that I can use those numbers instead of the filenames when telling git to do something.

So in your case I can save a lot of typing:

```
$ ga 1
```

(Assuming that 1 is the number that is associated with the very/deeply/nested/file/with-obscenely-long_and_tortured_name)

This is doable after I have done this:

```
$ alias gn='git number'
$ alias ga='git number add'

$ gn
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#1      very/deeply/nested/file/with-obscenely-long_and_tortured_name
#2      README
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ ga 1
```

You can read more about git-number at github: https://github.com/holygeek/git-number

Comment: Pretty awesome! Thanks I'll definitely be watching that repo :P

Answer (score 2):

I put this in my bash profile for adding and checking out long filenames

```
function gal() {
   git add "./*$1*"
}

function gcl() {
   git co -p "./*$1*"
}
```

gal "filename"

will add a file that has the string filename in it. This is wildcarded. Just need to use a unique name as the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer directly addresses your need, but I'll note that if `/very/deeply/nested/file/with-obscenely-long_and_tortured_name` is already being tracked by Git, and you've just changed it, then you can say `git add -u` to stage those changes. If there are other changes that you wish not to stage, that could be `git add -up` to let you decide piecewise.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of the following scripts to do what you ask.

I have this aliased to gga:

```
git ls-files -m -o --exclude-standard | grep $* | xargs -r git add
```

usage:

```
gga raptor # stages everything in raptor directory
gga Event #stages all files with Event in the name
```

you get the idea.

If I have to be more specific about things (because grepping isn't specific enough), I just use

git ls-files | grep

Then I just copy and paste the full path of the file into git add.

Comment: See the accepted answer above: git does enough globbing such that you do not need grep for simple cases like the ones you just described. Unless I'm missing something, in which case it might be useful to include such an example.

Comment: You are not missing anything, I simply find the syntax of `gga EventEdi` cleaner (and easier to remember) than `git add "./*EventEdi*"`