# How do I make path shorter for windows cmd? GIT

Tags: git

for git status how do i make the directory path shorter?

I just want the files to show to commit? i don't want to type in

htdocs/etc/etc/file.name

I just want to git add file.name

Thanks I'm on windows 8.1.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774439/stage-file-by-its-file-name-regardless-of-directory-git

Answer (score 1):

If `git status` shows changes only for `htdocs/etc/etc/file.name` you can do `git add htdocs` and it will add only changed files from htdocs.

If `git status` shows changes only from `htdocs` and there are no unadded files from any `htdocs/**` you can say `git add htdocs`.

From `git add --help`:

> **`<pathspec>…​`**
>   Files to add content from. Fileglobs (e.g. *.c) can be given to add all matching files. Also a leading directory name (e.g. dir to add dir/file1 and dir/file2) can be given to update the index to match the current state of the directory as a whole (e.g. specifying dir will record not just a file dir/file1 modified in the working tree, a file dir/file2 added to the working tree, but also a file dir/file3 removed from the working tree. Note that older versions of Git used to ignore removed files; use --no-all option if you want to add modified or new files but ignore removed ones.

You can also use wildcards `git add *file.name` but make sure it is what you want. You can do dry run to see what files will be added `git add --dry-run`.

> **`--dry-run`**
>   Don’t actually add the file(s), just show if they exist and/or will be ignored.